# Ad Mob works on test does not work other

Tags: ios, admob

I use Google Ad Mob for ios app.
It works when I run app in test device. But if I download from store, The app can not show the banner (empty banner view)
I also turn on the ios advertising settings.
Could anyone get this error before?
Thanks

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenHeigth = screenRect.size.height;

bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:CGPointMake(0, screenHeigth-kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height)];;

bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-../..";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[
                        @".."  ];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: have you comment code request.testDevices  befor your are submit app on appstore.

Comment: Check my answer and add your `GADBannerDelegate` methods to your question if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to comment out/remove:

```
request.testDevices = @[@".."  ];
```

And add:

```
bannerView_.delegate = self;
```

Make sure your Ad Unit ID is **exactly** the same as what AdMob has supplied you with.

```
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-../..";
```

Comment: In ios settings - advertising Turn Off the limited Adversiting to see Ad Mobs.

Comment: I dont have any delegate method for banner

Comment: You can remove your comment with your Ad Unit ID. Just wanted to make sure you had one in there. That *Limit Ad Tracking* has nothing to do with the delivery of your ads, [read here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202074). You have no methods that respond to receiving an ad, failing to load an ad, tapping on an ad? Check this [guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ad-events). As long as you remove/comment out your `request.testDevices = @[@".."  ];` as I mentioned in my answer you should be good to go but it may not be optimal.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I use delegate methods and it gives a log "adViewDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: No ad to show."

Comment: But still I can not understand what error is to get this error

Comment: Make sure you AD Unit ID is exactly what AdMob has supplied you with. You also need to add `bannerView_.delegate = self;`. I've updated my answer.